# Qual a diferença de performance entre tipos diferentes de concatenação de string?

Tags: c#, .net, string, desempenho, memória

Eu conheço 4 tipos diferentes de concatenação de *string* no c#:

```
// string Interpolation
$"valor {variavel} R$";

// Verbating string
@"texto qualquer
  pula a linha e continua o texto";

// concatenar 2 strings
"texto" + "texto";

// string.format
String.Format(variavel, " R$");

// Verbating string com string Interpolation
$@"UPDATE {variavel}
   SET campo = {variavel2}";
```

Até então eu sei para oque serve cada um dos comandos, mais gostaria de saber quais os impactos eles tem na memória e na performance.

Ex: se eu não me engano a concatenação usando o "+"

```
 "texto1" + "texto2"
```

Ele teria 2 referencias na memoria `"texto 1"`, `"texto2"` e quando ele concatena ele cria uma terceira com o resultado `"texto1 texto2"`.

Como funciona nos outros casos? Ou se o que expliquei esta errado (foi mais para facilitar a entender a minha dúvida).

Porque eu uso o Resharper e ele recomenda sempre o *string interpolation* e o *verbating string* e eu gostaria de saber até aonde ele facilita a leitura e até onde ele atrapalha a performance e na reciclagem de memória.

Um exemplo do código que o Resharper sugere para eu usar o *verbating string*

```
var texto = "texto";
```

[image: IDE mostrando o Resharper indicando]

ele sugere que fique:

```
var texto = @"texto"
```

[image: IDE mostrando o Resharper indicando]

Ele sugere mover para o *resource* a *string* ou usar o *verbating string*, e também sugere criar uma constante para a *string* que ele aponta.

[image: IDE mostrando o Resharper indicando]

Até onde facilita e quando atrapalha?

Comment: Verbatim com interpolação? Essa eu não conhecia...

Comment: @JeffersonQuesado https://pt.stackoverflow.com/search?q=verbatim+interpola%C3%A7%C3%A3o

Comment: @Maniero c# sempre sendo lindo

Comment: @Maniero Adicionei um exemplo que acontece com a sugestão do `resharper` com os prints, no caso quando usado uma string direta como no exemplo ele sugere essa edição para `interpolation string`

Comment: Ele permite fazer, não é que ele sugere, pode ser que deseje isto entre outras coisas, ele não está dizendo que é melhor fazer assim.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Parabéns, está acima da média :)

Só um deles é concatenação explícita, e nenhum é obrigado concatenar mesmo, alguma otimização poderia eliminar isto, se possível no caso.

Se estes são apenas exemplos artificiais, ferrou, porque eles talvez não aconteçam como espera, ou como em outros cenários, mas dá para falar de forma mais genérica.

Jura que o Resharper sugere isso dessa forma? Não faz sentido pra mim, na forma como postou.

> ```
> $"valor {variavel} R$";
> ```

Isso será transformado para um [`string.Format()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.format?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397) :) Eu queria uma solução mais simples, pelo menos para a maioria dos casos, mas é assim.

> ```
> @"texto qualquer
> pula a linha e continua o texto";
> ```

Vira uma coisa só e é o mesmo que não tivesse mais que uma linha, só que um caractere de pular a linha será incluso dentro da *string*, mas para todos efeitos é uma coisa só.

> ```
> "texto" + "texto";
> ```

Isso provavelmente será otimizado e virará uma única *string* na memória. Se o compilador não conseguir otimizar um caso um pouco diferente ele será transformado em [`string.Concat()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), aí internamente pode ser uma concatenação simples ou poderá usar um [`StringBuilder`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=net-8.0&WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397), ou pelo menos uma otimização dele.

> ```
> String.Format(variavel, " R$");
> ```

Acho que a sintaxe está errada, mas isso não vem ao caso.

[Veja o código fonte](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/shared/System/String.Manipulation.cs,412) (tem que ir seguindo os *links* nele). Ele faz algo próximo a um `StringBuilder` montando a *string*. Tem havido otimizações para reduzir alocações de memória (na verdade no *framework* todo hoje pode-se alocar bem menos do que antes, se souber o que está fazendo, e de fato alocação é algo ruim) e acho que vão otimizar mais. Se tudo correr bem não haverá alocações em excesso, uma só resolverá.

> ```
> $@"UPDATE {variavel}
> SET campo = {variavel2}";
> ```

É o mesmo já citado, haverá uma só *string* fazendo uma formatação, o que exigirá um custo para inserir os valores.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CSharp/Conceptual.md).